# JPA: data access in a bidirectional m:n relationship

Tags: java, jpa, entity

I want to model a sample m:n relationship between the entities 'order' and 'items'

The corresponding mapping sections are:

Order.java:

```
...
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="ORDER_ID")
private Long orderId;

@Column(name="ORDER_DESCRIPTION")
private String description;

@JoinTable(name ="ORDER_ITEMS",
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ORDER_ID", referencedColumnName="ORDER_ID"),
    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ITEM_ID", referencedColumnName="ITEM_ID"))
private Set<Item> items;
...
```

Item.java:

```
...
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ITEM_ID")
private Long itemId;

@Column(name = "ITEM_DESCRIPTION")
private String description;

@Column(name = "ITEM_PRICE")
private Long price;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="items")
private Set<Order> orders;
...
```

Do you know why I am not able to inversely get the orders referenced with a specific item? The part **@ManyToMany(mappedBy="items")** gives me an "invalid mapping type for this relationship". I thought I could just create arbitrary items and orders, add the items to the orders, and get subsequently all the orders regarding to an item.

In my case, an item.getOrders() gives me a NullPointerException.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply because you forgot to add the ManyToMany annotation on items:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name ="ORDER_ITEMS",
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ORDER_ID", referencedColumnName="ORDER_ID"),
    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ITEM_ID", referencedColumnName="ITEM_ID"))
private Set<Item> items;
```

Comment: You are right, it eliminates the "invalid mapping type for this relationship" but not the NullPointerException

Comment: The NPE is probably due to the fact that something is not initialized. Show us the relevant code, the stack trace of the exception, and tell us which line of code it refers to (by editing your question).

Comment: That´s it. I have not initialized the HashSet in the constructor. Now it works as expected! :) By the way: I removed the @ManyToMany on the non-owning side "Item". This works finde but now there are two joining tables created behind the wall. Can you explain that?

Comment: Why did you remove the ManyToMany in Item? You must not remove it.

Comment: Just temporary to inspect the behavior. Nevertheless, I wondered that it works.